# Consuming WCF service using javascript using WebScriptEndpoint

Tags: javascript, wcf, html

I searched on net but didn't find any suitable article explaining how to consume a WCF service using javascript, and especially a WebScriptEndpoint.

Can any one give any direction on this?

Thanks

Comment: _"Use [a WebScriptEndpoint] when you are writing a service that is called from an ASP.NET AJAX application."_ [Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.webscriptendpoint.aspx). Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster for editing my question :)

Comment: @CodeCaster I can't use script manager etc, no ASP.net.  want to consume service from my plain HTML5 page

Comment: I found a simple sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410778.aspx. Are there none in the WCF samples that come with WCF - see here http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=150780

Comment: Then why don't you simply implement a basicHttpBinding and perform SOAP calls on it from your HTML / javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article about REST services : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx

To summarize, you want an endpoint configured with webHttpBinding.
This endpoint should have a behavior with webHttp enabled :

```
<services>
  <service name="TestService">
    <endpoint address="test" binding="webHttpBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" contract="ITestService"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Behavior :

```
<behavior name="restBehavior">
  <webHttp/>
</behavior>
```

Then in your service interface :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "test?p={p}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string Test(string p);
}
```

You can use WebGet or WebInvoke attribute (depends if you want to GET or POST)...